# Mysql.connector to access remote database in local network Python 3

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I used mysql.connector python library to make changes to my local SQL server databases using:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import mysql.connector as kk

cnx = kk.connect(user='root', password='password123',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='db')
cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
sql = "DELETE FROM examples WHERE id = 4"
number_of_rows = cursor.execute(sql)
cnx.commit()   
cnx.close()
```

This works fine, but when i try the same code with a change only to the 'host' parameter, with something like,

```
host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

(where the IP is that of a server connected to my local network.), it won't update that particular data base in that server.

The error thrown is something like:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.x.xx' (10060)
```

Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you must check if your local IP can acces to your remote server (check if you are an IP restriction on your server), after check if your mysql database use the default port or not, If not you must precise the port in your code.

Comment: I checked if i can access that remote server by using a ping test. It works perfectly, but not sure how to check if my mysql database uses the default port or not.. How do i do that? Thanks

Comment: If your server was in a hosting service, your can check the mysql parameters in the control panel. For the ping, your server was accesible but maybe not the mysql base

Comment: I checked the port part, it says 3306. Now how do i mention the port ? Okay if ping doesn't guarantee the mysql database access, then how do i check if i have access?

Comment: The 3306 is the default port for mysql, so you don't have to precise in your connexion. But in your server, you need to authorize your mysql database to receive connexion from the outside. To do that, you need to ask the question with your host if you can't do in the control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database user you are using to connect to the database on the remote host has the correct access and privileges.

You can test this from the command line using:

```
mysql -u root -p password123 - h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx db
```

If this does not work then debug as follow:

1. ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. If host is reachable move on to next step, if not then this IP is blocked, not available or incorrect. Double check the IP and check that they are on the same network.
2. Check if mysqld is running on host. service mysqld restart. If it is move on to next step, if not start mysqld. If it does not want to start, install it, start the service and setup your database.
3. Telnet the specific port to see if the port is blocked. telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3306. If this works, move on to the next step. If this does not work, check your IPTables and check if the port is open on the remote host.
4. Add a user to the mysql on the the host: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html
   Restart mysqld and try the command above again.

Comment: "check your user on the remote host and check if the IP is available and that the port is not blocked (firewall)"  How do i check this? Thanks