# Can't connect Python program to remote MySQL database over the same network

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Can someone please help me? I am trying to make a simple python - MySQL connection. the code is running on my Dell-Windows Laptop, while the server is running on my Acer-Linux Laptop, they are connected on the same network. But upon running the query it prompts me with this error : Firewall is disabled for both. I tried pinging both of them vise versa and is working. In fact, I have a program with LibreOffice Base and they are interacting properly. But when I try to translate just a simple query in PYTHON seems like it is not working, I just don't know what could be the error on my code. Thank you so much for you help.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JM Dela Cruz\Documents\pyproj\myproject\test1.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\JM Dela Cruz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 287, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JM Dela Cruz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JM Dela Cruz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1095, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\JM Dela Cruz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 533, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\JM Dela Cruz\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 569, in open_connection
    raise InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '198.168.101.42:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

My Python Code :

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="198.168.101.42",
  user="vsearch",
  password="vsearchpasswd",
  database="classicmodels",
  port="3306"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

_SQL="Select * From employees"

myresult = mycursor.execute(_SQL)

print(myresult.fetchall())
```

Comment: `mysql -u root -p password123 - h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx db` are you able to connect from shell?

Comment: @msvstl, Yes I can. In fact, I am not using the root user, I made a user which only has the access to the table mentioned above. I also tried root but it didn't worked as well.

Comment: Did you try the checks mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50622189/13779320)?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Jhet. You are exposing your db credentials. Please if you don't want them to be exposed delete your question and post it again without your database credentials.

Comment: maybe MySQL is configured to run on `127.0.0.1` or to use files to connect with clients - and this way you can't access them from external computers. You should check if you can connect to MySQL from other computer using command `mysql` or programs like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/)